# Aplicar clase (active) a menu tabs al cargar el sitio

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un content tabs para mostrar diferente información en cada uno de ellos, pero necesito que al momento de que se carga el sitio o se entra a la sección correspondiente de cualquier enlace del menu, este muestre el estado activo en el primer enlace del menu.

Tengo el siguiente codigo JS:

```
 let menuSecondary = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tab-group-tabs > .nav_item'));

        const handleClick = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            menuSecondary.forEach((e) => {
                e.classList.remove('activo');
            });
            e.currentTarget.classList.add('activo');

        }

        menuSecondary.forEach((e) => {
            e.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
        });
        // menu secundario --//
```

Lo cual aplica correctamente la clase active o activo en este caso, pero al momento de cargar la pagina nuevamente esta clase no se aplica al menos que realizamos un click en el enlace, me imagino que esto es debido al addeventListener.

Alguna ayuda para poder lograr este objetivo?.

Answer (score 1):

Lo adecuado sería tener una función que puedas ejecutar con varios eventos e, incluso, dejar de asignar el evento `click` a los enlaces:

```js
// Obtener todos los enlaces
let links = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
// Función para mostrar sección activa y se ejecutará:
//    1. Al cargar la página
//    2. Cuando haya cambios de hash en la página actual
function linkActive() {
    // Recorrer enlaces, no se necesita Array.from(), el objeto es iterable
    links.forEach(link => {
        if(link.href == window.location.href) {
            // Marcar como activo si coincide con la URL de la ventana
            link.classList.add('activo');
            // Cargar contenido o mostrar contenedor
        } else {
            // De lo contrario, desmarcar
            link.classList.remove('activo');
            // Otras acciones, como ocultar contenedor
        }
    });
}
// Marcar enlace activo al cargar la página
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', linkActive);
// Marar enlace activo cuando haya cambio de hash
window.addEventListener('hashchange', linkActive);
```

```css
.activo { color:red; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#uno">Uno</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dos">Dos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tres">tres</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Nota:** En el fragmento de código, el enlace de inicio hace que se recargue la página, pero debería funcionar sin problema en tu proyecto al asignar una URL específica.